# Is it safe to pass 'arguments' to 'apply()'

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the following code (completely useless, I know)

```
function add( a, b, c, d ) {
  alert(a+b+c+d);
}

function proxy() {
    add.apply(window, arguments);
}

proxy(1,2,3,4);
```

Basically, we know that apply expects an array as the second parameter, but we also know that `arguments` is not a proper array. The code works as expected, so is it safe to say that I can pass any array-like object as the second parameter in `apply()`?

The following will also work (in Chrome at least):

```
function proxy() {
  add.apply(window, {
    0: arguments[0],
    1: arguments[1],
    2: arguments[2],
    3: arguments[3],
    length: 4
  });
}
```

**Update:** It seems that my second code block fails in IE<9 while the first one (passing `arguments`) works.
The error is `Array or arguments object expected`, so we shall conclude that it's always safe to pass `arguments`, while it's not safe to pass an array-like object in oldIE.

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ it be "safe"?

Comment: @Neal well `arguments` is a pretty strange beast, so some trepidation about its use is not unreasonable. In this case I can't imagine how it'd be a problem.

Comment: @Neal, maybe because `arguments` doesn't have many of the methods a normal Array has, and `.apply` may want to use them?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) writes: *"Calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided as an array (or an array like object)"*. So I think you're safe :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming ECMAScript 5.1: Yes.  As per ECMA-262, 10.6, the arguments object has the `length` and index properties that 15.3.4.3 (`Function.prototype.apply`) requires.

Comment: This is the shortest answer but is actually very spot-on on the matter of the safeness..do you know why my second test code fails in non-ECMASCRIPT 5 IE (<IE9) while the first one (passing `arguments`) works?

Comment: oh IE explicitely says: `Array or arguments object expected` so I guess it's safe to pass `arguments`, not safe to pass array-like objects

Answer (score 7):

From definition of `Function.prototype.apply` in **MDN:**

> `fun.apply(thisArg[, argsArray])`
>
> You can also use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) for the `argsArray` parameter. `arguments` is a
>   local variable of a function. It can be used for all unspecified
>   arguments of the called object. Thus, you do not have to know the
>   arguments of the called object when you use the `apply` method. You can
>   use `arguments` to pass all the arguments to the called object. The
>   called object is then responsible for handling the arguments.

**REF:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

As the second argument `apply` accepts *"an array like object, specifying the arguments with which function should be called"*. To my understanding, this array-like object should have the `length` property for internal iteration, and *numerically* defined properties (zero-indexed) to access the values.

And the same is confirmed my the **spec**: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3, as was kindly pointed out by [@Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543692/is-it-safe-to-pass-arguments-to-apply/#comment23761927_16543788).

Comment: Also [section 15.3.4.3 of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3) makes it explicitly clear that `apply` only looks at the value of `length` and the numbered (indexed) properties.

Answer (score 1):

MDN can only speak for Mozilla implementations. The actual [spec](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.3.4) to which all implementations should comply says the following:

```
15.3.4.3   Function.prototype.apply (thisArg, argArray)

When the apply method is called on an object func with arguments thisArg and
argArray, the following steps are taken:

1.  If IsCallable(func) is false, then throw a TypeError exception.
2.  If argArray is null or undefined, then
      Return the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of func,
      providing thisArg as the this value and an empty list of arguments.
3.  If Type(argArray) is not Object, then throw a TypeError exception.
4.  Let len be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of argArray
      with argument "length".
5.  If len is null or undefined, then throw a TypeError exception.
6.  Let n be ToUint32(len).
7.  If n is not equal to ToNumber(len), then throw a TypeError exception.
8.  Let argList be an empty List.
9.  Let index be 0.
10. Repeat while index < n
      a. Let indexName be ToString(index).
      b. Let nextArg be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of
         argArray with indexName as the argument.
      c. Append nextArg as the last element of argList.
      d. Set index to index + 1.
11. Return the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of func,
      providing thisArg as the this value and argList as the list of arguments.

The length property of the apply method is 2.

NOTE The thisArg value is passed without modification as the this value. This
     is a change from Edition 3, where an undefined or null thisArg is replaced
     with the global object and ToObject is applied to all other values and that
     result is passed as the this value.
```

It seems that property `length` and numeric index values are the only prerequisites.